# Show grand total for last column only

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is it possible to show the Grand Total for the last column only?

[image]

The other columns cannot be added.

I can either work with a table or matrix.

I'm trying with:

```
Measure = IF(ISFILTERED('Table'[Category]);SUM([Quant.]))
```

This hides the grand total but then it doesn't summarize rows by Category, ie, it shows all the items.

So all rows get a 1 for the measure above.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this without having to create an extra measure or use DAX.

I used a table and was able to get the following result that fits your requirements:

[image]

Check #1 - Make sure the values setting for only the third column **Valor Total** is set to Sum in the pull down (see image).  The two other columns you should set to **Don't summarize**.

[image]

Check #2 - Click on the table and make sure in the Paint roller settings for the visual, that the total setting is turned on (see image)

[image]

Comment: Hi @Tatherhead thanks! but I need to add the values of column "Quant.". Otherwise they all show 1.

Comment: For quant, change from Don’t summarize, to Sum also.

Comment: I thought you only had Number of Units, unit cost, and grand total.  It sounds like you have a category also.  Let me see what I can do.